# TFS Dashboard widget to display data of a differen tfs server

Tags: tfs, widget

I would like to display data of a different tfs server on a dashboard of another tfs project/server, its not a team project of the same server. I tried iFrame but how do I say it...it's crap. Destroys the performance of a Dashboard and to navigate within the widget is terrible.

So does anybody have a suggestion what I can use to display data from a different TFS Server or Queries?

Comment: Which TFS data you want to show on the dashboard?

Comment: A number (Remaining Work) of a Task Work Item